Can we check whether one *alleged* directed binary tree contains a cycle in O(1) space?
This is from sicp although a bit different:

Exercise 3.18.  Write a procedure that examines a list and determines whether it contains a cycle, that is, whether a program that tried to find the end of the list by taking successive cdrs would go into an infinite loop. Exercise 3.13 constructed such lists.
Exercise 3.19.  Redo exercise 3.18 using an algorithm that takes only a constant amount of space. (This requires a very clever idea.)

Here we consider one more general list where car part can be also list where car,cdr means left,right.
I found one similar QA Efficient algorithm to determine if an alleged binary tree contains a cycle?, but that is about undirected graph. O(1) is possible for that as Matt Timmermans's answer shows. IMHO that is right.

But for the above exercise context, we should think about directed binary tree since it is possible to go from the parent to the child by car or cdr but it is not ensured that we can also go in the reverse direction.
Q:
So is that possible to check whether one alleged directed binary tree contains a cycle with O(1) space complexity?
Any reference to be read when learning CRLS after I have learnt SICP with basic maths knowledge learnt in discrete maths is also welcome. Thanks in advance.

Note that O(log(n))-space and O(1)-space are often confused together. The answer which claims to do it in O(1)-space also claims to "create a few nodes", which presumably requires storing node ids, which requires log(n) bits. In practice, logarithm grows very very slow so the difference between O(1) and O(log(n)) is nonexistent, and a 64-bit variable is enough to store a node id. (2^64 is a huge number).

Since this question is the same as the one you linked to, I added an answer over there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79155823/5483526

@Stef pointer-sized values (including integer IDs) are typically considered to be O(1) size.

I'm going to mark this as a duplicate after people have had a chance to see it.  (My algorithm rep means that it would be marked right away instead of requiring 2 more votes)

@MattTimmermans Thank you for rephrasing my comment. It seems to me the OP was confused because some answers claimed to be proving that O(1)-space was not possible while another answer claimed to be proving that it was possible. Hence my comment that a O(log(n))-space solution would often be described as O(1)-space, hence the apparent contradiction.

I tink the difference is that in a directed graph with out-degree 2 a→b, a→c, b→d, c→d is not a cycle whereas the same nodes and edges considered undirected are. Why would this need another algorithm?

@greybeard At least for Matt Timmermans's implementation, the cycle test there doesn't hold for directed graph since it recognizes one cross edge instead of back edge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Output_of_a_depth-first_search (In your case, it will assert cycle existence for forward edge when c->d where d has been visited by a->b->d if we think that a.left=b, a.right=c, b.right=d, c.left=d). But only back edge implies cycle in directed graph https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/57736404#57736404 (actually that's in p4. I have one typo).

Reopened this question, since it now only wants to find directed cycles, whereas the linked question wanted to determine whether or not the graph was a tree.
